# How to formally give response message if my shop is closed

Tags: phrase-usage, sentence-usage

I'm trying to compose a response message for my Facebook page in case the page visitors send messages while my shop is closed (non business hours)

> Sorry our shop is closed at this hour, but our staff will serve your enquiry very soon, thank you.

My business is a salon service. How should I refer to my business in the message or any conversation? e.g. shop, store, etc.

Comment: I think "shop" works fine for a message like this.

Comment: You wouldn't "*serve* your enquiry", rather "*respond to* your enquiry".

Answer (score 2):

Indeed "**shop**" is just the word you need, no need to complicate things. However, you don't actually "*serve an enquiry*" but rather "*deal with an enquiry*", "*respond to an enquiry*", "*address an enquiry*", or "*process an enquiry*". I personally would go with "**respond to**" or "**address**".

Comment: Also, "enquiry" is the BE spelling. "Inquiry" is more common in AmE

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for calling (Name of Salon), located in (ex. downtown Seattle). We are currently closed. Our business hours are (days and times). Please pre-book your salon appointments online at (website), and make sure to check out our (Instagram, other Social Media) for current specials. If you'd like to leave a message, please do so or you may dial an extension. Thank you choosing Salon X.

Comment: You should refer as much as you can to your business by name. Be proud! You never know who might be listening. Salons are all about name recognition and word of mouth! Print it on your shirt, on your car, on flyers, on grocery store circulars, on church bulletins! Go for it!